# Recommended Cipher Suites for TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2

Tags: cryptography, network, tls

There are a lot of cipher suites defined in the in the specifications itself of TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2. And furthermore, there exist RFCs which add even more cipher suites to a specific version (e.g. RFC 4492 for ECC or RFC 4132 for Camelia).

Is there an official organization like for example [NIST](http://www.nist.gov/index.html) or [BSI Germany](https://www.bsi.bund.de) that has a list which cipher suites are considered to be safe? Or are all cipher suites offered by a specific TLS version safe to use?

Answer (score 9):

NIST maintains "Special Publication SP 800-52" for guidance with regards to TLS usage. On April 2014 was published [SP 800-52 Revision 1](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-52r1.pdf).

There are a lot of combinations of options, which cannot be readily shortened into an answer; you have to read the document to see what NIST really wants. See sections 3.9 (for servers) and 4.9 (for clients) for summaries of the NIST recommendations. Some highlights:

- NIST requires TLS 1.1 support, with TLS 1.2 being warmly recommended. SSL 2.0 and 3.0 are explicitly forbidden. TLS servers for "government-only applications" are required NOT to support TLS 1.0 either (so they really want to force usage of recent versions). Sysadmins are expected to "develop migration plans" for a general support of TLS 1.2 no later than January 1st, 2015 (so NIST is even in kind of a hurry)(I don't believe it will really happen so soon, though).
- They drop static Diffie-Hellman (nobody supports that anyway) and they finally embrace RSA. 2048-bit or longer keys, of course. ECDSA is also acceptable, using the P-256 or P-384 standard NIST curves.
- They recommend ECDHE cipher suites (and they much prefer ECDHE over DHE).
- Encryption shall be 3DES or AES. 3DES support MUST still be maintained (they insist on it, "for interoperability reasons"; one must assume that there still are a lot of deployed systems which do not support AES cipher suites).
- When using TLS 1.2, use of AES-GCM is, of course, recommended.
- They include an appendix which talks about Certificate Transparency, DANE (DNSSEC), Convergence... but they don't emit specific recommendations.
- There is not a single word, good or bad, about SRP. They *do* talk a bit about PSK cipher suites (and they recommend not using them).

Answer (score 7):

You might want to have a look at [RFC 6460 - *Suite B Profile for Transport Layer Security (TLS)*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6460). (Thanks to Jumbogram for highlighting the new RFC).

There are also some lists of known **weak** ciphersuites to avoid. You can find [some guidelines on testing those](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SSL-TLS_(OWASP-CM-001)#Testing_SSL_.2F_TLS_cipher_specifications_and_requirements_for_site) from OWASP.

And recently there's a little bit of a humdrum going on about BEAST, including several posts on stackexchange... here's [one of my favourites](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11363/how-do-i-use-openssl-to-test-for-the-beast-attack) :)

Comment: RFC 5430 has been replaced by 6460: http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6460.txt

Comment: I've updated the answer with the latest RFC